# How to use Yarn method to increase context length of an LLM?

Tags: python, hadoop-yarn, large-language-model, rope

I was following this git hub "https://github.com/jquesnelle/yarn" to increase the context length of huggingface models. But I'm getting a lot of errors. I've fixed most of it but they kept coming. So I would like to know has anyone successfully tried and worked out this method other than the authors themselves? If yes can you share if you'd faced any issues ?